# Entity Framework 6, DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int> is not giving option to convert to ToList()

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 to execute a stored procedure with the `Database.SqlQuery<TElement>` method, this method doesn't allow me to cast result in `ToList()`. It is has the option to cast to `ToListAsync()`, not sure why [image]

```
using (var context = new UserAddressContext())
{
    var Id = new SqlParameter("@Id", 1);
    var count = new SqlParameter("@UserAddressCount", 0)
            {
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
            };
    List<UserAddress> result= context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("GetUserAddressandCount @Id, @UserAddressCount OUT", Id, count).  --NOT GETTING OPTION AS "ToList()" 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DbRawSqlQuery` class returned by the `Database.SqlQuery` doesn't implement any `ToList()` method, so you can't convert result to a list directly. But it implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface so you should be able to use `ToList()` extension method of the `IEnumerable<T>`.

I guess, the reason, why this extension method isn't available, is the missing `using` statement, that brings extension methods from a nemaspace to the current scope.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas for answer, this works for me, I don't how I missed to check that...(